# How to format a mapping to an if statement?

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript

I'm had some trouble defining a mapping in my .vimrc. I want `<leader>sv` to source my .vimrc, but first I want to write, if I'm currently editing it.

#### Goal

The intention of the code is this:

```
if expand('%:p') ==? expand($MYVIMRC)
    write
endif
source $MYVIMRC<cr>
```

#### Attempt 1

I tried writing my commands inline with pipes:

```
nnoremap <leader>sv :if expand('%:p') ==? expand($MYVIMRC) | write | endif | source $MYVIMRC<cr>
```

But I get this error when I load it:

```
Error detected while processing /Users/jack/.vimrc:
E580: :endif without :if:  endif
```

#### Attempt 2

I also tried:

```
let s:source_vimrc='if expand('%:p') ==? expand($MYVIMRC) | write | endif | source $MYVIMRC'
nnoremap <leader>sv :exec(s:source_vimrc)<cr>
```

which got me:

```
E15: Invalid expression: 'if expand('%:p') ==? expand($MYVIMRC) | write | endif | source $MYVIMRC'
```

#### Attempt 3 (working)

The only way I can get it to work is using `<cr>` to simulate typing the whole thing out across multiple lines:

```
nnoremap <leader>sv :if expand('%:p') ==? expand($MYVIMRC) <cr> :write <cr> :endif <cr> :source $MYVIMRC<cr>
```

#### Attempt 4 (sort of?)

```
nnoremap <leader>sv :if expand('%:p') ==? expand($MYVIMRC) <bar> write <bar> endif <bar> source $MYVIMRC<cr>
```

That does it, but leaves me with `Press Enter or type command to continue` instead of returning to normal mode.

#### Questions

<del>Do mappings not support pipes for multiple commands? Or do `if`s not? Why didn't the first one work like I expected?</del>
A: Because the pipes are interpreted as new commands in the file. Use `<bar>` to get them written to the command line.

Why doesn't #4 return me to normal mode? When I type in the command (with `|`s), it does.

Note: I'm open to suggestions for better ways to accomplish this, too.

Comment: @SatoKatsura You're right. Fixed, retested, and edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: To avoid `Press Enter or type command to continue`, make your mapping a `<silent>` one. You can also increase your `cmdheight`. See `:h hit-enter`.

Comment: @VanLaser Ah, thanks. Now that I understand the problem, I can fix it by just taking out the extra spaces in the command. Want to make that an answer?

Comment: I only answered some small part of it; normally I would recommend the function-based approach (where possible). Perhaps, you could try to make an answer with the "final" working solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is where `<expr>` mappings are useful. From `:h <expr>`

```
                        *:map-<expr>* *:map-expression*
If the first argument to one of these commands is "<expr>" and it is used to
define a new mapping or abbreviation, the argument is an expression.  The
expression is evaluated to obtain the {rhs} that is used.  Example: >
    :inoremap <expr> . InsertDot()
The result of the InsertDot() function will be inserted.  It could check the
text before the cursor and start omni completion when some condition is met.
```

You can just use `expand('%:p') ==? expand($MYVIMRC)` in a ternary expression to find out if you want to write or not, and the concatenate that with `source ($MYVIMRC)`. Try this:

```
nnoremap <expr> <leader>sv (expand('%:p') ==? expand($MYVIMRC) ? ":w \|" : ":")."source $MYVIMRC<cr>"
```

If you run this in your `.vimrc`, it will evaluate to

```
:w | source $MYVIMRC
```

Otherwise, it will evaluate to

```
:source $MYVIMRC
```

This is assuming you want to source your vimrc either way (which I assume you do from the mappings you have shown). If not, you could just do

```
nnoremap <expr> <leader>sv expand('%:p') ==? expand($MYVIMRC) ? ":w \| source $MYVIMRC<cr>" : ""
```

Comment: Aha! Now that's why I added the line about being open to other suggestions. I didn't know `<expr>` or ternary operators were options. That's clearly a better way to do it.

Comment: +1. I came here from google. Thanks for pointing at `<expr>` I was struggling to get mapped a key which would open a file only if it exists: [here's the link to a question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/39117/mapping-a-key-to-open-a-file-only-if-exist/39119#39119).

Answer (score 5):

[DJMcMayhem's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/9575/9267) is better than what I was trying to do, but for posterity's sake, here is the information I was asking for. Short answers:

1. Use `<bar>` or `\|` in lieu of `|` in a map.
2. Don't print overlong lines to the command line.

---

#### Mistake 1: hitting the bars

Pipes/bars (`|`) separate multiple commands on one line on the command line, but they also separate multiple commands on one line in a script file. So my original attempt:

```
nnoremap <leader>sv :if expand('%:p') ==? expand($MYVIMRC) | write | endif | source $MYVIMRC<cr>
```

is parsed as these four separate commands:

```
:nnoremap <leader>sv :if expand('%:p') ==? expand($MYVIMRC)
:write
:endif
:source $MYVIMRC<cr>
```

The first two are valid, but not what I want. The third, `endif`, is not valid without its `if` buddy, and the fourth is a legal command, but points to a nonexistent file. Trying to parse those commands is what generates the errors I quoted.

Swapping the `|`s for `<cr>`s works around this problem by making the map print out each line as if I'd entered them separately:

```
:if expand('%:p') ==? expand($MYVIMRC)
:  write
:endif
:source $MYVIMRC
```

The direct solution is to use `<bar>` or `\|` in place of `|` in the map. That causes it to print a `|` at runtime, giving the expected behavior.

Credit to [@SatoKatsura](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9573/how-to-format-a-mapping-to-an-if-statement/9574?noredirect=1#comment16702_9574).

---

#### Mistake 2: sesquipedalianism

With `<bar>` in place of `|` it's like this:

```
nnoremap <leader>sv :if expand('%:p') ==? expand($MYVIMRC) <bar> write <bar> endif <bar> source $MYVIMRC<cr>
```

which works fine. However, it prints 71 characters to the command line, and I had my vim window squeezed to half width when I was testing. It turns out that entering a command longer than one line leaves the CLI on a `Press Enter or type command to continue` prompt.

There are a few ways to avoid this:

1. Use the `<silent>` argument to suppress all output. However, I wouldn't see any errors <del>if</del> when I mess up my .vimrc.
2. Make the window wider.
3. Increase the value of `cmdheight` to handle the extra lines.
4. Shorten the string. There are some spaces that could be removed.
5. Separate commands with `<cr>` to print multiple shorter lines.
6. [As DJMcMayhem showed](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/9575/9267), leave the logic to the script and print only the necessary commands, which are quite short.

Credit to [@VanLaser](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9573/how-to-format-a-mapping-to-an-if-statement/9574?noredirect=1#comment16707_9573).

Comment: Nice self answer, there's some good stuff in here! As a side note, you can also use `\|` in place of `<bar>` (which I used in my answer)

Comment: I sure learned a lot more than I would have if it had worked right the first time!
I'll slip `\|` into this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pipes for mappings, but I would recomend just wrapping it all in a function. Something like:

```
nnoremap <leader>sv :call SourceVimrc()<CR>

function! SourceVimrc()
    if fnamemodify('%', ':p') ==? expand($MYVIMRC)
        write
    endif
    source $MYVIMRC<cr>
endfunction
```

Comment: I tried exactly that, (and learned about `function!` in the process), but the `source` line throws an error because it redefines the function while the function is still in use. Oh wait, I could move `source` to the mapping ....

Comment: You're confusing `expand()` with `fnamemodify()`.  Try `expand('%:p', 1)` instead of `expand('%', ':p')`.

Comment: Okay, it worked that way: `nnoremap <leader>sv :call SourceVimrc()<cr>:source $MYVIMRC<cr>`.
But I'm still separating commands with `<cr>` rather than `|`, so we're back to a variation on my original question.

Comment: @P1h3r1e3d13 Use `<bar>` instead of `|` (or `<cr>`) as separators.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Oh, because `|` is interpreted as a new command *in the file*. Okay, so now my original works: `nnoremap <leader>sv :if expand('%:p') ==? expand($MYVIMRC) <bar> write <bar> endif <bar> source $MYVIMRC<cr>`, but after activating it, I get `Press Enter or type command to continue`. Why doesn't it just go back to normal mode? (It does when I type it into the command line with pipes.)

Comment: @SatoKatsura Yeah, you were right about confusing with `fnamemodify()`. I fixed that and edited the comment.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Want to make the `<bar>` tip an answer, or should I write one up?

Comment: Great, now you're confusing `fnamemodify()` with `expand()`. :) The former can't deal with `%` and friends.

Comment: @P1h3r1e3d13 I didn't provide a full answer, so please feel free to write it yourself.