# How to do a conditional key mapping dynamically?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, autocmd, key-bindings

I know that I can do a conditional key mapping by `map-expression`:

```
map [key] [condition] ? [foo] : [bar]
```

But now my situation is somehow awkward. I want to map `<C-h>` to `<C-w>h` if I have more than one windows in my VIM, and map it to `:bprev` if there is only one window in my VIM.

I've tried with

```
    nnoremap <C-h> winnr('$')>1 ? '<C-w>h' : ':bprev<CR>'
```

But it doesn't work as `.vimrc` is only read once when I start VIM. So I also tried with `autocmd` and failed. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Actually this is duplication of https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9573/how-to-format-a-mapping-to-an-if-statement ... Sorry for my negligence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the `<expr>` modifier:

```
nnoremap <expr> <C-h> winnr('$')>1 ? '<C-w>h' : ':bprev<CR>'
```

This conditional is evaluated *every* time the mapped key is sent, instead of once at mapping time.

Comment: Thanks so much, I found I didn't see `<expr>` in the doc...